# Why does lightdm source my .profile even though my login shell is zsh?

Tags: bash, zsh, profile, lightdm

I am using Linux Mint 19.2 Cinnamon, with ZSH as login shell for my user.

**When I login, I see that my `$PATH` includes `$HOME/.local/bin` two times, even though it is specified only once across all my ZSH startup scripts (in `$HOME/.zshenv`).**

I looked at the other dotfiles of my `$HOME`, and found the offending modification of the `$PATH` in `$HOME/.profile`:

```bsh
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

This was surprising, because the documentation of ZSH says that `.profile` is only sourced in a "compatibility" mode, when it is being invoked as `sh` or `ksh`:

> Zsh tries to emulate sh or ksh when it is invoked as sh or ksh respectively; more precisely, it looks at the first  letter  of  the  name  by  which  it  was  invoked,  excluding  any initial 'r' (assumed to stand for 'restricted'), and if that is 'b', 's' or 'k' it will emulate sh or ksh.   Furthermore,  if  invoked  as  su (which  happens on certain systems when the shell is executed by the su command), the shell will try to find an alternative name from the SHELL environment variable and perform emulation based on that.

I checked from where `.profile` was being source from by appending the following lines at the end of it:

```bsh
logger "Opened .profile with this shell: $SHELL"
PARENT_COMMAND=$(ps -o args= $PPID)
logger "Parent command: $PARENT_COMMAND"
```

After logging out and logging back in again, the syslog contained the following:

```
Opened .profile with this shell: /usr/bin/zsh
Parent command: lightdm --session-child 13 20
```

What is the sequence of events that leads the display manager `lightdm` to source `.profile` even though my `$SHELL` is ZSH, and what is the rationale behind it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the Arch-Linux Wiki page for `lightdm`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/LightDM#X_session_wrapper) (which I imagine may be valid for your situation in Linux Mint too):

> If you are migrating from `xinit`, you will notice that the display is not launched by your shell. This is because, as opposed to your shell starting the display (and the display inheriting the environment of your shell), LightDM starts your display and does not source your shell. LightDM launches the display by running a wrapper script and that finally exec's your graphic environment. By default, `/etc/lightdm/Xsessions.conf` is run.
>
> Environment variables
>
> The script checks and sources `/etc/profile`, `~/.profile`, `/etc/xprofile` and `~/.xprofile`, in that order. If you are using a shell that does not source any of these files, you can create an `~/.xprofile` to do so. (In this example, the login shell is `zsh`)
>
> `~/.xprofile`
>
> ---
>
> ```
> #!/bin/sh
> [[ -f ~/.config/zsh/.zshenv ]] && source ~/.config/zsh/.zshenv
> ```

So, get your `~/.profile` file sourced because that's what the wrapper scripts of `lightdm` does when it starts. The wiki text furthermore has a *specific example for `zsh` users* which includes sourcing your `~/.zshenv` from `~/.xprofile`.

The `#!`-line in that example doesn't make much sense though as the file is sourced and therefore shouldn't need it, and I wonder if they got the order of parsing right as it would make more sense to prioritise `~/.xprofile` over `~/.profile` (i.e don't read `~/.profile` at all if `~/.xprofile` exists).

If the suggestion in that wiki doesn't do it for you, you can get your `~/.profile` to source `~/.zshenv` when read by `zsh` by using

```sh
case $SHELL in (*/zsh) . "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zshenv"; return ;; esac
```

or

```sh
if [ "$SHELL" = "/usr/bin/zsh" ]; then
    . "${ZDOTDIR:-$HOME}/.zshenv"
    return
fi
```

at its top.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the wrapper script `/usr/sbin/lightdm-session` was indeed responsible for explicitly sourcing `$HOME/.profile`, regardless of the login shell. For future readers, the relevant line in the LightDM code base can be found [here](https://github.com/canonical/lightdm/blob/1.26.0/debian/lightdm-session#L38).

Comment: Interestingly enough, there were a few occurrences of people arguing about this topic. Some people are [in favor](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/794315) of LightDM sourcing `.profile` while some are [strongly against](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1468832).

Answer (score 0):

In case this helps someone: I'm sourcing `zshenv` from `.xsessionrc`. Apparently it's executed just by `/bin/sh`, so the commands needs to be [`dash` (POSIX) compliant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell#dash):

```bash
if test "${SHELL##*/}" = "zsh" ; then
  # shellcheck disable=SC1091
  test -r /etc/zsh/zshenv && . /etc/zsh/zshenv
fi
```

In particular `[[ ... ]]` and `source` don't work.